# Exit status 1 set after postfix increment from 0 to 1

Tags: bash

I have a script that is using the `++` (postfix increment) operator. However the exit status is being set in a way that surprises me. To reproduce:

```sh
▶ i=0
▶ ((i++))
▶ echo "$?"   ## Huh?
1
▶ echo "$i"
1
▶ ((i++))
▶ echo "$?"
0
▶ echo "$i"
2
```

I did not expect `((i++))` to set exit status 1 when incrementing from 0 to 1 but not otherwise. Meanwhile, this works just as I did expect:

```sh
▶ i=0
▶ ((i+=1))
▶ echo "$?"
0
```

As does this:

```sh
▶ i=0
▶ ((++i))
▶ echo "$?"
0
```

Is this a bug? If not, why is the postfix increment operator setting exit status 1 when incrementing 0 to 1 but not otherwise?

(Seen in Bash version 5.0.18(1)-release for Mac OS X and version 4.4.20(1)-release for Linux.)